# What is the right way to communicate between child and parent component to change view content in Parent in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a child component where I have a button.

Now I have three of these child components placed next to each other in one Parent component.

Whenever any of these child comp is touched, I wish to change stuff in my parent component. So whenever the button is clicked, I wish to change state (or whatever is the way to do it) in parent and then go on and change the list that. I am loading in another child component used in parent. But when I press those buttons, my app just freezes after 3-4 clicks every time.

I thought maybe I am doing something very basic wrong. Like using the state/prop wrong and sending the app to infinite loop or something.

Parent Component:

```
export default class Dash extends PureComponent {
constructor(){
    super();
    // Bind the this context to the handler function
    this.state = {
        activeAuctionsCount: 15,
        wonAuctionsCount: 10,
        convertedLeadsCount: 6,
        isActiveAuctionsSelected: true,
        iswonAuctionsSelected: false,
        isconvertedLeadsSelected: false,
        cardSelected: 'auctions', /* auctions/won/leads */
    };
    this.loadActiveAuctions = this.loadActiveAuctions.bind(this);
    this.loadWonAuctions = this.loadWonAuctions.bind(this);
    this.loadconvertedLeads = this.loadconvertedLeads.bind(this);
}

// This method will be sent to the child component
loadActiveAuctions() {
    console.log('active pressed');
    this.setState({
        cardSelected: 'auctions'
    });
}
loadWonAuctions() {
    console.log('won pressed');
    this.setState({
        cardSelected: 'won'
    });
}
loadconvertedLeads() {
    console.log('leads pressed');
    this.setState({
        cardSelected: 'leads'
    });
}

render() {
    return (
                            <DealerShipDashStatsCard 
                            statCardLayoutPath={statCardLeft}
                            statCardTitle={'NOW'+"\n"+'SHOWING'}
                            statValue={this.state.activeAuctionsCount}
                            isSelected={this.state.isActiveAuctionsSelected} 
                            action={this.loadActiveAuctions}
                            />                         
                        </View>
```

Child Component:

```
export default class DealershipDash_StatsCard extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Rendering DashStat Card "+ this.props.statCardTitle);
    return (
      <ImageBackground 
      source={this.props.statCardLayoutPath} 
      style={styles.stat_card} 
      resizeMode="cover"
      resizeMethod="resize">
        <View style={styles.cardTop}></View>
        <View style={styles.cardBottom}>
            <View style={styles.cardStatTitle}>
                <Text style={[styles.statTitleText]}>{this.props.statCardTitle}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.cardStatValue}>
                <Text style={styles.cardStatValueText}>{this.props.statValue}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.cardButton}>
                <Image 
                source={this.props.isSelected ? cardButtonActive : cardButtonInactive } 
                style = {this.props.isSelected ? styles.stat_card_button : styles.stat_card_button_inactive}/>
            </View>
        </View>
        <Button onPress={this.props.action} title="press"/>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or not the react way? (this is my First project with react)

I am also sometimes getting `Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected` warning in my metro bundler. When i check console, I see everything is getting re-rendered on every click, maybe that's making it so slow that it finally gives up?

Comment: From the code you've given it looks like you're doing everything correctly, perhaps the issue is in the code for your buttons? Can you post more of your code, or could you try to create an example using https://codesandbox.io/s/new that reproduces the issue you're seeing?

Comment: There is no error produced, the app just freezes after a few clicks. It freezes even if I click once and then wait for a few seconds. I'll try and post the child component code.

Comment: Nothing stands out as obviously wrong, other than your `Dash` component is defined as a `PureComponent` but your `DealershipDash_StatsCard` component is defined as a regular `Component` (the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) recommend against that). The only other suggestion I'd have would be to try to narrow down the issue by taking out code (for example, change the child component to only be a button) to see which prop/style/component is causing the issue?

Comment: @BrileyHooper : I was using regular component for both earlier. But later I wondered if high res images and re-rendering those again and again is causing the freeze. Then someone suggested me to use PureComponent to avoid too much re-rendering. Though that didn't help. Can it be due to the way I'm fetching these images? I'm using something like `const statCardLeft = require('../../assets/dealership-dash-stats-card-left.png');`

Comment: You could find out easily by removing the images and seeing if it still freezes. I wouldn't expect that to be the issue, especially if that `require()` code is outside the render function (which it should be, since it doesn't change at all between renders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, eventually. I was not using [PureComponent](https://codeburst.io/when-to-use-component-or-purecomponent-a60cfad01a81) for the header component that had a ticking clock. This made the header (with a few images inside) re-render entirely every second. As a result, [JS frame rate](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html) for my app was dropping too low, hence the freezing.

Answer (score 2):

Every things looks pretty good but if you add the default props for child it will become more readable for other developers.